# How to search in splunk : documentID = NM_APEXIT,{FFAAAA8-59EB-457F-A831-B532CACF20C1},{6080D6666-666-C00B-999C-3C42BBBBBB}

Tags: splunk

How to search in splunk : `documentID = NM_APEXIT,{FFAAAA8-50EB-457F-A831-B532CACF20C1},{6080D6666-666-C00B-999C-3C42BBBBBB}`

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as putting what you want to find the in search box. `documentID =" NM_APEXIT,{FFAAAA8-50EB-457F-A831-B532CACF20C1},{6080D6666-666-C00B-999C-3C42BBBBBB}"`.